# Save screen state before rebooting my laptop

Tags: gnu-screen

I love using [gnu-screen](/questions/tagged/gnu-screen) and I'm always opening loads of windows inside it.

The problem is that when I need to shutdown my laptop for whatever reason, I have to loose these windows and when I turn on my laptop I've lost my screen session and its windows.

Is there a way to save the [gnu-screen](/questions/tagged/gnu-screen) state before turning it off?

Answer (score 1):

In short: no.

A bit longer answer:
Gnu Screen is only a text-mode window manager. It does not have the capability of actually making sure a process state is saved into disc and ability to restore it on next launch.

Such functionality is built into for example macOS, but given complexity of that even Windows operating system doesn't have that feature.

Suggested improvement:
As a long-time fan of Gnu Screen, I have all the typical windows in my `.screenrc`. Day-to-day life is handled by detach/resume, but when there is no detached Screen-session to resume, a new Gnu Screen session will always spawn my favorite apps into screens of my choosing.

An example:

```
# Genric settings
startup_message off
vbell on

# Screen 0: mutt mailer (will alert on changes)
screen mutt
title Mail
monitor

# Screen 1: bash shell
screen 1

# Screen 9: Epic5 IRC-client
screen 9 nice epic5
title IRC

# Go back to screen 0
select Mail
```